# Shortcut Doesn't Launch The File In Android Q

Tags: android, android-shortcutmanager

**Edit:**

I am getting below logs in `system_process` when I click the pinned shortcut:

```
2019-10-26 20:00:16.086 2047-3533/system_process I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/AAD.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity bnds=[439,84][641,337]} from uid 10147
2019-10-26 20:00:16.100 2047-2047/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } U=0: not found
2019-10-26 20:00:16.100 2047-2047/system_process W/RemoteAppPredictionService: could not bind to Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } using flags 67108865
```

In short, pinned shortcut isn't getting opened in Android 10 but works in older versions. In Android 10, when I click the shortcut, Drive PDF Viewer opens but actual file is shown with black space and within a second, the app closes.

OLD:

My Android app targets API level 28. It pins shortcut of a PDF file to home screen and clicking on the icon opens the file obviously. Till Android Pie, it worked really fine. But when I tested it on API 29, clicking the icon opens the PDF Viewer and force closes with no error. Here's the relevant code.

```
private fun addShortcutInOreo(path1: String, pdfName: String) {
        val file = File(path1)
        try {
            Log.d("Data", file.path)
            val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

            val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)

            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
            pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

            Log.d("DataPath", uri.path)
            Log.d("DataPath", pdfName)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 25) {
                val shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)

                // Check which icon is to be pinned
                image = if (blueIcon.isChecked)
                    R.drawable.pdf
                else
                    R.drawable.pdf2

                // Create a shortcut
                val shortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, pdfName)
                        .setShortLabel(pdfName)
                        .setLongLabel(pdfName)
                        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, image))
                        .setIntent(pdfIntent)
                        .build()

                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcut, null)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            errorMessage(e)
        }

    }
```

The logged data is here. First line shows file path. Second line shows the Uri. Third line simply gives the extracted File Name. I did this just to check if everything is fine with my code.

```
2019-08-02 13:43:14.160 3306-3306/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/Data: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Nakal.pdf
2019-08-02 13:43:14.160 3306-3306/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/DataPath: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Nakal.pdf
2019-08-02 13:43:14.160 3306-3306/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/DataPath: Nakal
```

The logs are the same for API 28:

```
2019-08-02 13:55:07.853 5341-5341/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/Data: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Nakal.pdf
2019-08-02 13:55:07.853 5341-5341/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/DataPath: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Nakal.pdf
2019-08-02 13:55:07.853 5341-5341/com.parassidhu.pdfpin D/DataPath: Nakal
```

Since there's no error, I'm scratching my head as what could be gone wrong. I have read about Scoped Storage in Android Q but that doesn't apply here as I am not targeting Q. I have read about other behaviour changes in Android Q but none does apply as far as I read.

What could be the issue? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare's hint, I solved the problem. I made two changes:

1. For Android 7.0 and up, I used `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` instead of `Uri.fromFile()` as suggested by @CommonsWare.
2. Instead of using `setFlags()` (In Kotlin's syntax, it's `intent.flags = <flag>`), I used `addFlags()` and passed `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.

**Explanation:**

1. The first change was really necessary since using the `Uri.fromFile()` method caused `FileUriExposedException` for Android 7.0+. Not in the app since when the shortcut is clicked, started activity doesn't belong to my app. That is why I couldn't catch it.
2. This change was the main culprit I guess. If we don't add the given flag, the PDF opening activity (or app) doesn't have the permission to read the file contents (or uri). That is why the activity opens for a second and closes since it's unable to read the file.

Regarding the `setFlags()` vs `addFlags()`, since `setFlags()` removes existing flags and adds the specified flag, it didn't work. But `addFlags()` retains the existing flags and adds the specified flag. Hence `addFlags()` worked.

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.fromFile()` has been effectively banned since Android 7.0, as it triggers a `FileUriExposedException`.

Use `FileProvider` in your app and `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to create the `Uri` to use in your `Intent`.

Comment: I am not getting this exception and I have already tried this. Didn’t work for me.

Comment: @ParasSidhu: "I am not getting this exception" -- you wouldn't be, since your process is not the one starting the activity. "Didn’t work for me" -- you need it anyway, as few apps will respond to `ACTION_VIEW` for a `file` `Uri`. Plus, `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` only work for a `content` `Uri` anyway.

Comment: True, got it. I inspected more what's going on under the hood in `system_processes` and didn't find any relevant error.

Comment: I think I have solved the issue with your help. Using the `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` method and using `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` instead of `setFlags()` did the trick. I will be testing for more full confirmation and will award you the bounty if it works fine afterwards :)

Comment: @ParasSidhu: Ah, yes -- that's one of the downsides of Kotlin's simplifying syntax (combined with Google's tendency to use bitfields instead of `enum` values for flags). I should have noticed that, and I apologize for missing it in my earlier review. I am glad to hear that you have it working!